# setOnCancelListener and dismiss listener don't work on custom Dialog

Tags: android, dialog

First of all I use: https://github.com/javiersantos/MaterialStyledDialogs
as library for my dialogs.

**I build them in this way:**

```
MaterialStyledDialog dialog = new MaterialStyledDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
                        .setTitle("Image information")
                        .setCustomView(customView)
                        .show();
```

...
I need to check when the **dialog is closed (by touching outside the dialog)** as I have to set an `AtomicBoolean` on `false`

**I tried using:**

```
dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                        isDialogAlreadyOpen.set(false);
                    }
                });
```

and `onDismissListener`on the dialog but they don't get triggered, any idea or workaround for this problem, **like checking if the dialog is still on the screen / instantiated?** I don't want to change libary, I am pretty happy with this one.

Comment: Use `dialog.show();` after all data set

Comment: @StanislavBondar I do that, that's not the problem? What do you mean by it?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this issue](https://github.com/javiersantos/MaterialStyledDialogs/issues/45) and [this wiki](https://github.com/javiersantos/MaterialStyledDialogs/blob/master/README.md#adding-buttons-and-callbacks). As I understood there is no `setOnCancelListener` or `setOnDismissListener`. You need to handle yourself. If you give a callback for each button you can achieve that. Such as

```
.onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
        Log.d("MaterialStyledDialogs", "Do something!");
})
```

Inside `onClick` you can set `isDialogAlreadyOpen.set(false);`

Comment: Does not work, the touched outside event is ignored

Comment: `.setCancelable(false)`  or change the library :)

Comment: I am pretty sure there is a workaround, without changing the whole library